# Django send email with form data filled in my user

Tags: django

I am trying to create a send mail option after the user fills in form. this email should have all customer's form data and sent to administrators only. Following the Django Docs and I am able to send mails however I can not customize a mail template. See code

```
    subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
    text_content = 'This is an important message.' 
    html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>',
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot customize a mail template"? What doesn't work?

Comment: Getting user data into the email

Answer (score 0):

It's the next line [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types):

> By default, the MIME type of the body parameter in an EmailMessage is "text/plain". It is good practice to leave this alone, because it guarantees that any recipient will be able to read the email, regardless of their mail client. However, if you are confident that your recipients can handle an alternative content type, you can use the content_subtype attribute on the EmailMessage class to change the main content type. The major type will always be "text", but you can change the subtype. For example:

```
msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.send()
```